# How to control a background script (python) to do some task? (preferably using a terminal command)

Tags: python, service, terminal, background, task

So I have set up a script that will alert me when my laptop battery is over 90 (prevent overcharging) or below 15 (prevent dying). What I want is to be able to disable the alert for overcharging. I thought about making a boolean to determine whether or not to send the alert. But how would I control the value of that boolean from a command line when the program is already running in the background.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    if overcharging():
        send_overcharging_alert()
    elif dying():
        send_dying_alert()
```

what I hope to do is this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    if overcharging():
        if overcharging_alert_enabled:
            send_overcharging_alert()
    elif dying():
        send_dying_alert()
```

How do I change the value of the variable `overcharging_alert_enabled` without restarting the program?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, what you need is to be able to change the configuration of your script during runtime. One way you could do that is to have the configuration in a file (e.g. a .ini file) and have your program re-read it every time before you take action:

```
import configparser


def read_config(path_to_configuration_file):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    
    config.read(path_to_configuration_file)
    
    return config


def loop(path_to_configuration_file):
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        config = read_config(path_to_configuration_file)
        
        if overcharging() and config.getboolean("alerts", "overcharging_alert_enabled"):
            send_overcharging_alert()
        elif dying():
            send_dying_alert()
```

And the ini file:

```
[alerts]
overcharging_alert_enabled = 1
```

Comment: Well I thought of that and it seemed to me that there must be a better way to do it instead of reading config every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of a boolean while the program is running, I'd suggest using the keyboard module. Just run `pip install keyboard` to install it, and you might use it as follows (keep in mind that this module may require admin permissions, if that's an issue for you):

First, have a variable called "toggle_key" that specifies which key of the keyboard will toggle the boolean variable. I've chosen "q", but you can chooose whatever you'd like. Also, make sure to initialize the overcharging alert boolean variable.

```
toggle_key = "q"
overcharging_alert_enabled = True
```

In the while loop, have a condition to check if the key has been pressed, and if so, toggle (switch) the value of the boolean variable.

```
if keyboard.is_pressed(toggle_key):
    overcharging_alert_enabled = not overcharging_alert_enabled
```

This would be it normally, but since your loop is sleeping every sixty seconds, it would only check for the keypress every sixty seconds, meaning that in order to toggle the variable, you would have to press the toggle key exactly every sixty seconds, which is nearly impossible. To get around this, I removed the `time.sleep(60)` from your loop and created a new timing system.

```
initial_time = time.time()
current_time = 0
interval = 60 # how often you want the loop to execute

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(toggle_key):
        overcharging_alert_enabled = not overcharging_alert_enabled

    if current_time - initial_time >= interval:
        initial_time = current_time
        current_time = time.time()
    else:
        current_time = time.time()
        continue

    if overcharging():
        if overcharging_alert_enabled:
            send_overcharging_alert()
    elif dying():
        send_dying_alert()
```

The program stores the initial time in the `initial_time` variable, and then calculates the current time with `time.time()`. If their difference is greater than the interval, the execute the rest of the loop and reset the times. Otherwise, continue so the rest of the loop is not executed. This solution should meet your needs.